# Operators overloading and polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading, wrapper

I'm writing a simple wrapper to basic numeric types in C++.

I want to have an abstract base class Number and a few derived classes like Short, Integer, Long and Double.

For the Number class to be abstract I need to declare some pure virtual methods that are common for all numeric types, for example basic operators (+, -, *, /):

```
class Number {
    public:
    [...]
        virtual Number operator+(Number) = 0;
        virtual Number operator-(Number) = 0;
        virtual Number operator*(Number) = 0;
        virtual Number operator/(Number) = 0;
    [...]
}
```

but I'm afraid this will not work when I will try to implement that operators in derived classes but with the concret types like:

```
class Integer : public Number {
    public:
    [...]
        Integer operator+(Integer);
        Integer operator-(Integer);
        Integer operator*(Integer);
        Integer operator/(Integer);
    [...]
}
```

when I try to compile this code I get this kind of messages:

> Number.hpp error: cannot declare parameter 'anonymous’ to be of abstract type ‘Number’
>   note: because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Number’:
>   note: virtual Number Number::operator+(Number)

I'm sure I can do this, but so far I have no idea how. Could you please help me a little? ;)

Comment: A Number is not an Integer. So those functions in Integer do not override the functions in Number.

Comment: You will need to take the parameter by `Number const&` in both the base and derived class. Also, `operator+` and so on usually delegate to `operator+=`.

Comment: You are not defining the pure members in the derived class: Only the return type and default-parameters may be different (return-type must be co-variant).

Comment: `I'm sure I can do this, but so far I have no idea how.`  Well the question then is "how you knew you can do this if you don't know how?"

Comment: since you made `Number` as abstract, you have to implement the base class's pure virtual functions in the derived class.

Comment: I doubt that it's really so simple... You'll have to manage all the possible combinations (i.e. Integer*Double), find a way to create Numbers (which is abstract, so you'll need a kind of factory), and find a way to copy/assign Numbers by avoiding slicing.

Comment: I think the question should be, why in the world would you want to do something like this?

Comment: I would make the `+=` operators virtual, and the `+` style operators non-virtual and call `+=`

Comment: You should make your operator return `unique_ptr<Number>` or some such, because if you want polymorphic behaviour, you need pointers.

Comment: `I'm writing a simple wrapper to basic numeric types in C++.`  Unless you're writing a "big number" or arbitrary precision class, I don't see the point in doing what you're doing.  Also, what if I want to do an operation with your Number class but use a plain old int, and not an Integer?  Then you might end up in the murky waters of type conversion where you least expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You must return a reference (or pointer), since Number is abstract
2) The parameter must also be a reference (same reason)
3) the parameter to the derived class must be the same
4) you are missing 'virtual' on the overrides

Here's a hack that kinda works:

```
class Number {
    public:
        virtual Number& operator+(const Number&) = 0;
};

class Integer : public Number {
    public:
        virtual Integer& operator+(const Number&) override;
    private:
        int i;
};

Integer& Integer::operator+(const Number& n)
{
    static Integer i;
    const Integer* param = dynamic_cast<const Integer*>(&n);
    assert(param);
    i.i = this->i + param->i;
    return i;
}
```

Note, returning a reference to a static can surprise you in some cases, see comments. 
 Also, polymorphism might not be the best fit for what you are trying to do, for example,
do you really need to keep track of numbers, that you don't know what type they are?

If you really want polymorphism here, smartpointers should probably accompany the solution

Comment: You might want to name some of the ways in which it completely falls apart.

Comment: Interesting ! But **returning a reference to a static will not be a well defined result** (see also https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=23).  Did you try your code with  (a+b)+(d+e). With my compiler it returns 2*(a+b), because he calculates (d+e), stores the result in the static, the does (a+b), sotres the result in the (same) static, and then adds 2 times the static....

Comment: Your current usage of a static makes your code non-rentrant (two threads using the same function at the same time will lead to undefined results). Don't return a reference to `operator+`. RVO optimization will take care of redundant copies. Just create the local object and return it.

Comment: @Christophe you are right, I can see the same behaviour as you mentioned.

Comment: @tillaert this is what I need - return a copy. But I'm unable to return a copy since operator+ is a polimorphic function derived from Number class. Any other ideas?

Comment: @crooveck You could return a `std::shared_ptr<Number>` object and reference an `Integer` object. The `Number` class should define         `virtual std::shared_ptr<Number> operator+(Number) = 0;` and the `Integer` class should implement the same signature. That way you prevent slicing and do not need to create a non-local reference.